# how to use sudo command without password in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, sudo

I am developing cocoa application for mac. In my application I want to create bandwidth pipe. I am using command "sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 50" to create bandwidth pipe.
My problem is that its asking for user password when execute this command. How can i execute this command using objective-c without asking password?

I read somewhere that it can be achieved by inserting "user_name ALL=NOPASSWD ALL" in visudo file. I tried this and found that by inserting this entry in visudo file its not asking for password.

My query is that is there any other method to run this command without password or is there any method to insert "user_name ALL=NOPASSWD ALL" in visudo???

Comment: You're a little confused - `visudo` is the *command* for editing the `/etc/sudoers` *file*. But no user in their right mind is going to allow your app to sudo without permission on their system.

Comment: Yes visudo is command for editing the /etc/sudoers file. But I need to use it. Is there any other method with which I can set downloading and uploading bandwidth of my system for particular server or any method to run command without password??

Comment: You'll probably just have to put up an authentication dialog so that the user can enter an admin password - note however that not all users will have access to an admin password, so you should fail gracefully if they cancel.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me that how can I run sudo command with providing password within it and also get output of command in cocoa programming?